# Convert to AnsyncTask Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to Android development, I am working on a App and I want to convert my below mentioned code to AnsyncTask. Because it is showing me Run-time error that I am doing too much work on UI thread. Please help me to convert it to AnsyncTask.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GridView gridview;
TextView textView;
TextView result;
TextView remainingChance;
Button giveup;
Button goback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blanks);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    remainingChance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remainingChance);

    giveup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.giveup);
    goback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goback);

    goback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent goBack = new Intent(PlayActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(goBack);
        }
    });

    String dash = "";
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String easyArray[] = bundle.getStringArray("easy");

    final String randomStr = easyArray[new Random().nextInt(easyArray.length)]; // Getting a random string from Array
    giveup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(randomStr); // By clicking on Give up button, it displays the actual word & a message Go Back and try again
            remainingChance.setText("Go Back and try again");
        }
    });

    final Integer strLength = randomStr.length();

    // Creating string with question mark with 2nd and 5th character only
    for(int i=1; i<=strLength; i++){
        if(i == 2){
            dash = dash+Character.toString(randomStr.charAt(1));
        } else if (i == 5){
            dash = dash+ Character.toString(randomStr.charAt(4));
        } else {
            dash = dash + "?";
        }
    }

    final String displayVal = dash;

    textView.setText(displayVal); // Displaying string with question mark with 2nd and 5th character only

    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    final String[] mAlphabets = new String[]{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};


    final ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(mAlphabets));
    final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array_list);
    gridview.setNumColumns(8);
    gridview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    gridview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    gridview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        String finalDisplayVal = displayVal;

        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlayActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Checkinggg...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
            long delayInMillis = 1000;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, delayInMillis);

            String itemValue = (String) gridview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            array_list.remove(position); // Removing character from 26 alphabets which is clicked by user
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Reset gridview

            if(randomStr.contains(itemValue)){ // If selected alphabets exists in string
                for(int k=0; k<strLength; k++){
                    if(Character.toString(randomStr.charAt(k)).equalsIgnoreCase(itemValue)){
                        int charPos = randomStr.indexOf(itemValue);
                        while(charPos >= 0){
                            finalDisplayVal = replaceCharAt(finalDisplayVal, charPos, itemValue);
                            textView.setText(finalDisplayVal);
                            charPos = randomStr.indexOf(itemValue, charPos + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                checkWinCount(); // Checking if User Wins
            } else {
                count++;
                int remVal = 4-count;
                remainingChance.setText("Not Exist, You have " + remVal + " chance(s) left.");
            }
            checkLoseCount(); // Checking if User Lose
        }

        public String replaceCharAt(String s, int pos, String c) {
            return s.substring(0, pos) + c + s.substring(pos + 1);
        }

        public void checkLoseCount() {
            if(count > 3) {
                Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, "You Loose, Value is: "+randomStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent goBack = new Intent(PlayActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(goBack);
            }
        }

        public void checkWinCount(){
            if(randomStr.equalsIgnoreCase(finalDisplayVal)){
                Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, "Hurray!!! You WIN... It's "+randomStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent goBack = new Intent(PlayActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(goBack);
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

AsyncTask Code;

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class PlayActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

GridView gridview;
TextView textView;
TextView result;
TextView remainingChance;
Button giveup;
Button goback;
int count = 0;
String randomStr;
String finalDisplayVal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blanks);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    remainingChance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remainingChance);

    giveup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.giveup);
    goback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goback);

    goback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent goBack = new Intent(PlayActivity1.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(goBack);
        }
    });

    String dash = "";
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String easyArray[] = bundle.getStringArray("easy");

    final String randomStr = easyArray[new Random().nextInt(easyArray.length)]; // Getting a random string from Array
    giveup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(randomStr); // By clicking on Give up button, it displays the actual word & a message Go Back and try again
            remainingChance.setText("Go Back and try again");
        }
    });

    final Integer strLength = randomStr.length();

    // Creating string with question mark with 2nd and 5th character only
    for (int i = 1; i <= strLength; i++) {
        if (i == 2) {
            dash = dash + Character.toString(randomStr.charAt(1));
        } else if (i == 5) {
            dash = dash + Character.toString(randomStr.charAt(4));
        } else {
            dash = dash + "?";
        }
    }

    final String displayVal = dash;

    textView.setText(displayVal); // Displaying string with question mark with 2nd and 5th character only

    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    final String[] mAlphabets = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};


    final ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(mAlphabets));
    final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
    gridview.setNumColumns(8);
    gridview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    gridview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    gridview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
            String finalDisplayVal = displayVal;
            runner.execute(finalDisplayVal);

            String itemValue = (String) gridview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            array_list.remove(position); // Removing character from 26 alphabets which is clicked by user
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Reset gridview

            if (randomStr.contains(itemValue)) { // If selected alphabets exists in string
                for (int k = 0; k < strLength; k++) {
                    if (Character.toString(randomStr.charAt(k)).equalsIgnoreCase(itemValue)) {
                        int charPos = randomStr.indexOf(itemValue);
                        while (charPos >= 0) {
                            finalDisplayVal = replaceCharAt(finalDisplayVal, charPos, itemValue);
                            textView.setText(finalDisplayVal);
                            charPos = randomStr.indexOf(itemValue, charPos + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                checkWinCount(); // Checking if User Wins
            } else {
                count++;
                int remVal = 4 - count;
                remainingChance.setText("Not Exist, You have " + remVal + " chance(s) left.");
            }
            checkLoseCount(); // Checking if User Lose
        }

    });

}

public String replaceCharAt(String s, int pos, String c) {
    return s.substring(0, pos) + c + s.substring(pos + 1);
}

public void checkLoseCount() {
    if (count > 3) {
        Toast.makeText(PlayActivity1.this, "You Loose, Value is: " + randomStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent goBack = new Intent(PlayActivity1.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(goBack);
    }
}

public void checkWinCount() {
    if (randomStr.equalsIgnoreCase(finalDisplayVal)) {
        Toast.makeText(PlayActivity1.this, "Hurray!!! You WIN... It's " + randomStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent goBack = new Intent(PlayActivity1.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(goBack);
    }
}

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, ProgressDialog> {

    @Override
    protected ProgressDialog doInBackground(String... params) {

        final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlayActivity1.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Checkinggg...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
        try {
            long delayInMillis = 1000;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, delayInMillis);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mProgressDialog;


    }
}


}
```

Comment: I don't think you will get help if you ask people to completely write code for you. Try something out yourself first, and come back and ask questions if you get stuck on specific tasks.

Comment: As per your code I can see that you have to create two AsyncTask. First is to set `GridView` and other is `setOnItemClickListener` of gridview.

Comment: @Lawrance Thank you, will try it.